# Implicit casting to union type?

Tags: c, getter-setter

Let's say we have the following parameters describing a person: **name** (string) and **age** (unsigned int). I want to write a universal setter API function that someone can call to set either the name or the age of a specific person. The reason for that will be explained later below.

What I did is define an enum type of person parameter names:

```
typedef enum person_param_name
{
    NAME,
    AGE,
} person_param_name_t;
```

And also a union type for person parameter values:

```
typedef union person_param_val
{
    char* name;
    unsigned int age;
} person_param_val_t;
```

Now, the function can look like this:

```
int set_person_param(person_param_name_t param_name, person_param_val_t param_val)
{
    int ret = 0;

    switch (param_name)
    {
        case NAME:
            g_person_name = param_val.name;
            break;
        case AGE:
            g_person_age = param_val.age;
            break;
        default:
            ret = -1;
            break;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that one can't simply call the setter function like this (compiler throws warning):

```
set_person_param(NAME, "Alex");
set_person_param(AGE, 5);
```

But they have to explicitly cast the param value to `person_param_val_t` type, like this:

```
set_person_param(NAME, (person_param_val_t)"Alex");
set_person_param(AGE, (person_param_val_t )5);
```

The reason I want the universal setter function is because in the real program, I have a lot more parameters (close to 100) and I would need to write many (very similar) setter functions which would take a lot more lines of code.

Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Do you know that setting the `age` will destroy the `name` and vice-versa?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `_Generic`

Comment: @Barmar _Generic will make mess. At the moment I am not sure if OP knows what **union** is

Comment: @0___________ They're assigning different variables, so nothing is being destroyed.

Comment: I cant understand then why two different unions instead one struct.  It looks like X-Y problem for me

Comment: You can use compound literals: `set_person_param(NAME, (person_param_val_t){ .name = "Alex"});
set_person_param(AGE, (person_param_val_t ){ .age = 5} );`

Comment: *"I would need to write many (very similar) setter functions which would take a lot more lines of code"*, 4 lines for a setting function as opposed to 3 lines to add a case isn't that much more, and it's more clear.

Comment: @dbush do you understand why union and strange global variables

Comment: In regard to your example code, neither `(person_param_val_t)"Alex"` nor `(person_param_val_t )5` will work. The C standard defines only casts to `void` or scalar types, not to unions (or structures or arrays).

Comment: sounds like a job for a simple macro , no unions or any such fancy stuff

Comment: People do not have _either_ a name or an age. They have _both_ a name and an age. And it is perfectly possible to have an age and a name at the same time. So it would be more sensible to store both age and name in a struct, then find a way to mark either item invalid. For example both members could be pointers to data set to NULL when not initialized.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Casting to unions is not a part of standard C, but GNU C extension allows it.

Comment: @A6SE: If you want to allow the extensions of a particular compiler, it should be stated in the question and added as a tag. The default meaning of the C tag is the standard: “This tag should be used with general questions concerning the C language, as defined in the ISO 9899 standard (the latest version, 9899:2018, unless otherwise specified…)”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the union so that the field names are identical to the enum constants:

```
typedef union person_param_val
{
    char* NAME;
    unsigned int AGE;
} person_param_val_t;
```

Then you can create a macro which will pass a properly initialized compound literal:

```
#define set_person_param_ext(k,v) \
        set_person_param(k, (person_param_val_t){.k=v})
```

So then this:

```
set_person_param_ext(NAME, "Alex");
set_person_param_ext(AGE, 5);
```

Will expand to this:

```
set_person_param(NAME, (person_param_val_t){.NAME="Alex"});
set_person_param(AGE, (person_param_val_t){.AGE=5});
```

Answer (score 2):

I could see:

```
typedef enum person_param_name {
    NAME,
    AGE,
} person_param_name_t;

typedef union person_param_val
{
    char* name;
    unsigned int age;
} person_param_val_t;

person_param_val_t person_param_val_init_charp(char *name) {
    return (person_param_val_t){.name=name};
}
person_param_val_t person_param_val_init_u(unsigned age) {
    return (person_param_val_t){.age=age};
}
#define MAKE_PERSON_PARAM_VAL(x)  _Generic((x) \
    , unsigned: person_param_val_init_u \
    , char *:person_param_val_init_charp \
    )(x)

int set_person_param(person_param_name_t param_name, person_param_val_t param_val);

#define set_person_param(a, b) \
    set_person_param(a, MAKE_PERSON_PARAM_VAL(b))
    
int main() {
    set_person_param(NAME, "Alex");
    set_person_param(AGE, 5u);
}
```

With GCC with extension, you will get away with just:

```
#define set_person_param(a, b) \
     set_person_param(a, (person_param_val_t)(b))
```

But I would not write such code. This is C. In C, you would write it all explicitly. I do not see a value in `person_param_name`. You *still* have to enumerate all types explicitly inside `set_person_param`. I would just write `set_person_param_age(unsigned age)` and `set_person_param_name(char *name)` explicitly. If not, I would consider rethinking the whole approach, as most probably you want to implement virtual function. I would advise, *strongly* consider not writing an interface with endless number of cases in enums, because you might end up with [this](https://github.com/Gurux/GuruxDLMS.c/blob/master/development/src/gxserializer.c#L802). Instead, create objects with a pointer to the interface stored with a vtable.

Comment: Where are magic `g_...` variables as in the OP example

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any magic. This macro is enough

```
#define set_person_param(param, val)  g_person_##param.param = (val)
```

And this sample function:

```
int foo(void)
{
    person_param_val_t g_person_name, g_person_age;

    set_person_param(name, "Alex");
    set_person_param(age, 5);
}
```

will be preprocessed to:

```
int foo(void)
{
    person_param_val_t g_person_name, g_person_age;

    g_person_name.name = "Alex";
    g_person_age.age = 5;
}
```

As I understand it was something you wanted to archive. Your enum type is not needed.

If you want `val` to be the same union type then:

```
#define set_person_param(param, val)  g_person_##param = (val)
```

example:

```
    set_person_param(name, (person_param_val_t){.name="Alex"});
```